# Pandas: transform a DataFrame by splitting each value into multiple values

Tags: python, pandas

I'd like to extract the point values and frequencies of Scrabble letters. Wikipedia gives the following table (copied from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrabble_letter_distributions#English
).

```
# English Scrabble points (rows) and frequencies (columns).
scrabble_table = """
    ×1  ×2  ×3  ×4  ×6  ×8  ×9  ×12
0       (Blank)                     
1               L S U   N R T   O   A I E
2           G   D               
3       B C M P                     
4       F H V W Y                       
5   K                           
8   J X                         
10  Q Z                         
"""
```

which I can import as a DataFrame without any problems.

```
pd.read_table(io.StringIO(scrabble_table), index_col=0).fillna("")
```

Image of [resulting table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wC2Dp.png).

This table has values such as "L S U" in the 1-point row and 4-frequency column. I'd like a table that has one row per letter and three columns: letter, frequency, and point value. Can someone suggest how I transform my original table to get what I want? Thanks.

Comment: Can you show what this loaded df looks like, when I run your code I get 0 columns and a very long list as a single value

Comment: Sorry — tabs became spaces when I pasted into Stack Overflow. I've added a link to an image of the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the spaces in, say, `L S U` are to be ignored, let's first remove all spaces:

```
scrabble_table = scrabble_table.replace(' ', '')
```

Now read the table into a DataFrame.

```
df = pd.read_table(StringIO(scrabble_table), delimiter=',', index_col=0)
```

To move the column level values into a new index level, use `stack()`. Since there are no more column levels, `stack()` returns a Series. `reset_index()` moves the index levels into columns:

```
df = df.stack().reset_index()
#     level_0 level_1        0
# 0         0      ×2  (Blank)
# 1         1      ×4      LSU
# 2         1      ×6      NRT
# 3         1      ×8        O
# 4         1      ×9       AI
# 5         1     ×12        E
# 6         2      ×3        G
# 7         2      ×4        D
# 8         3      ×2     BCMP
# 9         4      ×2    FHVWY
# 10        5      ×1        K
# 11        8      ×1       JX
# 12       10      ×1       QZ
```

To place `(Blank)` on an equal footing with the other tiles, let us replace it with a single character, such as an underscore (`_`).

```
df = df.replace('(Blank)', '_')
```

and while we're at it, let's name the columns meaningful names:

```
df.columns=['points', 'freq', 'letters']
```

Now we can form a list comprehension that iterates over the rows using `df.iterrows()`, and for each row, iterate over the letters to form a list of tuples. Each tuple consists of the three values: `(row['points'], row['freq'], letter)`. Passing this list comprehension to `pd.DataFrame` yields the desired result:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([(row['points'], row['freq'], letter) 
                   for index, row in df.iterrows() 
                   for letter in row[-1]], columns=['points', 'freq', 'letter'])
```

---

To make the code easier to cut-and-paste, I've replaced the tabs with commas:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

try:
    # Python3
    from io import StringIO
except ImportError:
    # Python2
    from StringIO import StringIO


scrabble_table = u'''\
,×1 ,×2 ,×3 ,×4 ,×6 ,×8 ,×9 ,×12
0, ,(Blank)
1,,,,L S U ,N R T ,O ,A I ,E
2 ,,,G ,D
3 ,,B C M P,,,,
4 ,,F H V W Y
5 ,K
8 ,J X
10 ,Q Z'''
scrabble_table = scrabble_table.replace(' ', '')
df = pd.read_table(StringIO(scrabble_table), delimiter=',', index_col=0)
df = df.stack().reset_index()
df = df.replace('(Blank)', '_')
df.columns=['points', 'freq', 'letters']
df = pd.DataFrame([(row['points'], row['freq'], letter) 
                   for index, row in df.iterrows() 
                   for letter in row[-1]], columns=['points', 'freq', 'letter'])
print(df)
```

yields

```
    points freq letter
0        0   ×2      _
1        1   ×4      L
2        1   ×4      S
3        1   ×4      U
4        1   ×6      N
5        1   ×6      R
6        1   ×6      T
7        1   ×8      O
8        1   ×9      A
9        1   ×9      I
10       1  ×12      E
11       2   ×3      G
12       2   ×4      D
13       3   ×2      B
14       3   ×2      C
15       3   ×2      M
16       3   ×2      P
17       4   ×2      F
18       4   ×2      H
19       4   ×2      V
20       4   ×2      W
21       4   ×2      Y
22       5   ×1      K
23       8   ×1      J
24       8   ×1      X
25      10   ×1      Q
26      10   ×1      Z
```